# How can I prove that if $x^5-x^3+x=2$, with $x$ a real number, then $x^6>3$, using only middle school algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can I prove that if $x^5-x^3+x=2$, with $x$ a real number, then $x^6>3$, using only middle school algebra?

I have been struggling with this one. And I can't find any solution that doesn't rely on derivatives.

Comment: It works like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766411/finding-first-approximation-for-newtons-method-without-graphing?noredirect=1), but one has to use something at least. The real root $a$ satisfies $a>1.205$.

Answer (score 7):

Notice the alternating signs in $x^5-x^3+x$, it's tempting to write it as a fraction

$x^5-x^3+x=x(x^4-x^2+1)=x\frac{x^6+1}{x^2+1}$

Now the equation becomes $x\frac{x^6+1}{x^2+1}=2$. To prove $x^6>3$, we just need to prove $\frac{x^2+1}{2}>x$, which is simply $x\neq 1$ and can be easily verified by putting 1 back to the equation.

(As pointed out in the comment, we also need the fact that x>0, which can easily be proved based on the fraction form of the equation.)

Comment: Again, using that inequality works if $x>0$, else it would get reversed...   Thankfully your expression as a fraction does show that $x$ must be positive for it to be a root.

Comment: @Macavity You're right! Added to the answer.

Comment: I don't know that middle-schoolers know how to turn polynomials intro fractions (in fact, even for me this idea is outside of the box), but still, for anyone who has good ideas, this is rather elementary. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$x^5-x^3+x=2\Longrightarrow x^6=2x-x^2+x^4\cdots (1)$

Also we have  $\displaystyle x^4=\frac{2}{x}+x^2-1\cdots\cdots \cdots \cdots \cdot (2)$

From $(1)$ and $(2),$ we have

$\displaystyle x^6=2x-x^2+\frac{2}{x}+x^2-1=2\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)-1$

$\displaystyle x^6=2\bigg[\underbrace{\bigg(\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\bigg)^2}_{\geq 0}+2\bigg]-1\geq 3$

Equality hold when $x=1$

But from $(1),$ We have $1=2$

So we have $\displaystyle x^6>3$

Comment: That works only for positive roots, if $x<0$ we have $x+1/x<-2$ instead.  Hence to use that you would first have to show there are no negative roots.

Comment: Thank you very much!
First, pupils in middle-school know that x+1/x>2, so yeah, your solution is on point. It's great!

It would have been nice if instead of finding out what x^4 is, we could have just found out the value (relational) of x^6 without first finding out the value of x^4, like, just do it all in one go, but still, it's manageable.

I don't know how to choose the best answer of all the answers, but yours is the best one here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more straightforward but much more laborious reasoning that doesn’t use derivatives or any meaningful calculus. First, since

$$2=x^5-x^3+x=x\cdot\underbrace{(x^4-x^2+1)}_{>0},$$

we have that $x$ is positive. Now we prove that $f(x)=x^5-x^3+x$ strictly increases. Let $0<x<y$. We want to prove that

$$x^5-x^3+x < y^5-y^3+y$$

$$(x-y)(x^4+x^3y+x^2y^2+xy^3+y^4-x^2-xy-y^2+1)<0.$$

Since $x-y<0$, we want to prove that the second factor is positive. It follows from these AM-GMs:

$$x^4+\frac13\ge 2\sqrt{x^4\cdot\frac13}\ge x^2,$$

$$y^4+\frac13\ge 2\sqrt{y^4\cdot\frac13}\ge y^2,$$

$$x^2y^2+\frac13\ge 2\sqrt{x^2y^2\cdot\frac13}\ge xy.$$

Now, knowing that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing, let us see that $x>\frac65$. Indeed, otherwise $$x^5-x^3+x<\left(\frac65\right)^5-\left(\frac65\right)^3+ \frac65=\frac{6126}{3125}<2.$$

Now $$x\cdot(x^5-x^3+x)=x\cdot 2$$

$$x^6-x^4+x^2=2x$$

$$x^6=x^4-x^2+2x.$$

Knowing that, we consider

$$x^6>3$$

$$x^4-x^2+2x-2>1$$

$$x^2(x+1)(x-1)+2(x-1)>1$$

$$(x-1)(x^2(x+1)+2)>1$$

Since $x>\frac65$ the LHS is a product of two positive increasing functions and thus is increasing. So if this inequality is true for $\frac65$ then it’s true for $x$:

$$\left(\frac65\right)^4-\left(\frac65\right)^2+2\cdot\frac65=\frac{1896}{625}>3.$$

Proof complete.

Comment: I think the AM-GM inequality is beyond middle school math.

Comment: @ErycSnyder AM-GM for two numbers is just a figure of speech, anyway. $a+b\ge 2\sqrt{ab}$ can be easily rewritten as $(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})^2\ge 0$. Completing a square is quite of middle school level.

Comment: AM-GM is not beyond middle-school math.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer I feel that would be about the level of middle school (but coming from a high schooler)... I've only used a tiny bit of basic AM-GM Inequality:

$x^5-x^3+x=2$. Taking out x as a common factor and since x is clearly non zero, we get:

$x^4-x^2+1=\frac{2}{x}$. I will use this later.

Now in our original equation, we can rewrite as: $x^5=x^3-x+2$
Multiply x on both sides here to obtain

$x^6=x^4-x^2+2x$. Use from earlier that $x^4-x^2+1=\frac{2}{x}$ to obtain

$x^6=\frac{2}{x}-1+2x$. Using AM-GM Inequality we get $\frac{2}{x}+2x$ >= $2\sqrt{(2x)(\frac{2}{x})}$.

Thus $x^6>= 4-1$ (Equality holding at $2x=\frac{2}{x}$ or $x=1,-1$).  Now notice that when we put $x=1$ into $x^5-x^3+1$, we get $1$ and not $2$. Neither does putting x=-1 satisfy the original equation. Which would imply $x^6>3$, equality removed.